# The query does not use partial hash indexes, but partial B-tree indexes and full hash indexes are used

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I think all three indexes can be used by the query, but the behavior of the hash part index puzzles me. Why it cannot be used

Here is an example

```sql
drop table if exists example;
create table example
(
    id    serial4 primary key,
    value int not null
);
```

I inserted 1000000 rows, 9954 rows value is 0.

Then start the test

```sql
-- Explain With Partial Hash Index
drop index if exists example_value;
create index example_value on example using hash (value) where value = 0;
explain select id from example where value = 0;

-- Explain With Partial Btree Index
drop index if exists example_value;
create index example_value on example using btree (value) where value = 0;
explain select id from example where value = 0;

-- Explain With Full Hash Index
drop index if exists example_value;
create index example_value on example using hash (value);
explain select id from example where value = 0;
```

The Test Results

```
-- Explain With Partial Hash Index
Gather  (cost=1000.00..11749.03 rows=10967 width=4)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on example  (cost=0.00..9652.33 rows=4570 width=4)
        Filter: (value = 0)

-- Explain With Partial Btree Index
Bitmap Heap Scan on example  (cost=172.73..4753.82 rows=10967 width=4)
  Recheck Cond: (value = 0)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on example_value  (cost=0.00..169.99 rows=10967 width=0)

-- Explain With Full Hash Index
Bitmap Heap Scan on example  (cost=332.99..4914.08 rows=10967 width=4)
  Recheck Cond: (value = 0)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on example_value  (cost=0.00..330.25 rows=10967 width=0)
        Index Cond: (value = 0)
```

PostgreSQL Version

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.5 (Ubuntu 12.5-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

Comment: Why your obsession with hash indexes? They hardly ever provide a benefit over B-Tree indexes (and if they do, it's more a size advantages, not a speed advantage)

Comment: Unrelated, but: the "version output" you have posted is the version of `psql`, not the version of the Postgres server. To get the real server version, it's better to use `select version();` - not `psql --version`

Comment: I want to learn more about PostgreSQL indexes in my spare time, purely out of interest. I hope my question is not bad